# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present ; Apache cassandra - spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I'm using the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I need to query on `users` table which is present in `myks` keyspace

From my controller part I'm calling the service

```
userService.authenticateUser(username, password);
```

And in the service method I have a call to repository

```
logger.info("Here : " + username);
boolean userExists = userRepository.existsById(username);
logger.info("userExists : " + userExists);
if (userExists) {
    User user = userRepository.findByusername(username).get();
    return user;
}
return null;
```

and the below is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    Optional<User> findByusername(final String username);
}
```

Suppose in the table I don't have an entry with the user `kri_test` and user sends an input with the username `kri_test` then I'm facing the exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`

Even it is not printing the log statements present in service class

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with Cassandra configuration etc. You are getting Optional.empty() from `userRepository.findByusername(username)`. And you call `get()` method on that without calling `isPresent()` first.

You can fix your problem with this one liner;

```
return userRepository.findByusername(username).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are two controllers, so when we try to call any controller mostly we use URL for calling any kind of controller.
1.You might done mistake in URL or
2.you are trying to call that data which is not inside service class.

```
@RequestMapping("/topics")//URL
public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {
    return topicService.getAllTopics();     
}
@RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id){
    return topicService.getTopic(id);
}
```